# Do Bootstrap popover's copy elements instead of moving them? (click handlers not working..)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I created a DIV with some buttons in it that have click event handlers specified in an external JS file.

I've been trying to figure out why the click events don't trigger when I click buttons in the popover, but then I noticed when I type in the jQuery selector for the button's class in the console (after opening the popover) two elements show up instead of one.

This makes me think that Bootstrap popovers make copies of the element specified in the `content: function() { return $("element"); }` property when initializing it.

Is that the case?

If so, is there any way to get click handlers working if the elements are being copied instead of moved?

Example HTML:

```
<div class="popoverHtml" style="display: none">
    <span class="btn btn-default popoverInnerBtn">Click me, too!</span>    
</div>

<span class="btn btn-default popoverTriggerBtn">Click me</span>
```

JS:

```
$(".popoverTriggerBtn").popover({
    animation: true,
    html: true,
    placement: 'bottom',
    trigger: 'click',
    container: 'body',
    content: function() { return $(".popoverHtml").html(); }
});

$(".popoverInnerBtn").bind("mousedown", function(e) {
    alert("yay!");
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw2nwbLd/)

As you can see, the event is not triggered because apparently when an element is copied the events are not copied with it (why is that?).

If you modify the code for the inner button to have an `onclick` attribute, then the attribute is copied when the popover is triggered and the code is run:

```
<span class="btn btn-default popoverInnerBtn" onclick="alert('yay!');">Click me, too!</span>
```

Unfortunately, I really need to bind the events in an external JS file if possible.

Comment: *"Is that the case?"* ~ yes. *"is there any way to get click handlers working"* ~ yes, use event delegation. If you show the code that registers these *click handlers*, you may get more than just comments here :)

Comment: @Phil Sorry for not including code -- fixed.

Comment: See the answer below for an example of using event delegation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I've edited this answer to make it work**

please provide us with your current code for the popup/javascript and buttons.. my understanding is the following should work

```
<button type="button" id="popover" class="btn btn-default" data-html="true" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-content="<button id='popoverbutton'>Test</button>">
    Popover on left
</button>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#popover").popover();
      $(document).on("click", "#popoverbutton", function() {
           alert('it works!');
      });
  });
```

This has a button which when hovered over, will produce a popover with another button inside that popover which is clickable (and alert's here).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `event.delegation` in this case as your html is replaced by new one try it like,

```
$(document).on("mousedown",'.popoverInnerBtn', function(e) {
    alert("yay!");
});
```

See **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/Lw2nwbLd/1/)**